# Angular DI - How to inject generic component-provided services in a guard / deactivate guard

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I need to inject services in guards and these services are provided on components. Now from what I learned about Angular's DI, this cannot be done very easily - or maybe at all - because guards use the root injector.

I am looking for other ways to accomplish this. Here is my scenario.

Within `ParentFeature`, there can be multiple implementations of generic `ChildComponent`s. Each of these implementations provide a slew of services on generic tokens.

**Child Component 1**

```
Component({
  providers: [
    { provide: GenericService1, useClass: Child1GenericService1},
    { provide: GenericService2, useClass: Child1GenericService2},
  ],
  template: 'some generic component selectors here',
})
export class ChildComponent1 {}
```

**Child Component 2**

```
Component({
  providers: [
    { provide: GenericService1, useClass: Child2GenericService1},
    { provide: GenericService2, useClass: Child2GenericService2},
  ],
  template: 'some generic component selectors here',
})
export class ChildComponent2 {}
```

Providing these services in the parent feature is not possible because the last ones listed would be the ones provided on the generic injector tokens, having overwritten anything that came before.

I need to inject some of these services in guards used on routes nested within these child components, but anything provided on a component is not available to guard injectors.

As a bit of additional context, I will probably end up with 25 to 30 implementations of these child components, and any one of my features can use zero to many of these child component implementations as siblings.

Please let me know if I can provide any additional info or improve my question in any way.

Comment: Can u try accessing the component in with gaurd via ActivatedRouteSnapshot > component ?

Comment: I know we can send extra data to the with gaurds using data in routing definitions but in your case you need to access services that are used in components right

Comment: Right. These are essentially stateful services (partly ngrx store facade, partly actual state) that make the child component and its children do their thing. I need access to said state, for example, in a deactivate guard to warn the user of unsaved changes before leaving

Comment: I've never tried that stuffs but do check ActivatedRouteSnapshot for component access.

Answer (score 1):

Some guards like `DeactivateGuard` provide access to the component instance.

If you declare the service injected into the component as public you will be able to access the service from the guard via the component param in guard

```
@component
class AbcComponent {
    constructor(public myService) {}
}

@service()
class MyGuard {
    canDeactivate(component: AbcComponent, ...other params) {
         component.myService.methodOfChoiceCalled();
    }
}
```

But most probably you might require to access component services while navigating away i.e in a `DeactivateGuard`. But if you are trying to access component services in other guards like `CanNavigate` then something else could be wrong with your design.

Also as you have access to component it would be better to add a public method to the component called by guard which in turn calls the required service

Comment: I would definitely not make the services public in the component. They can do things a deactivate guard has no business knowing about. I will play with this a bit, I think it will probably solve the deactivate guard use case

Comment: Regarding `CanActivate`, I accept that I may have a design flaw. I will flesh out my question with a specific use case later this weekend